# what's the disadvatage of callStackSymbols

Tags: objective-c, ios, plcrashreporter

In the article [Reliable Crash Reporting](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/2011/09/14),Landon Fuller said it's better not to use [NSThread callStackSymbols],but can i use [exception callStackSymbols] when i want to get the full symbolic call stack and send it to my server?

Answer (score 2):

They get their stack the same way, but the timing is different - NSThread one will get you the callstack at the time you send the `callStackSymbols` message, and the NSException one will get you the symbols at the time the exception occurred.

Comment: But why Landon Fuller doesn't recommend get the stack by **callStackSymbols** ?And in his PLCrashReporter he use callStackReturnAddresses to get the pointers,why not log the symbolic stack by **callStackSymbols**

Comment: As of iOS 6, symbolizing the crash report on the device will just return <redacted> for most of the symbols. The only way to get around the <redacted> is to symbolize the crash on a mac or use private frameworks (which might get your app rejected). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156342/stack-trace-method-names-redacted