# Stack trace method names redacted

Tags: ios6, stack-trace

I have users email me stack traces when my app crashes on their device. Prior to iOS 6 they looked like this:

```
CRASH: NSInvalidArgumentException (*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil)

TRACE: (
0  CoreFoundation                      0x355e58a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
1  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3798c259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2  CoreFoundation                      0x3553a1d7 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 186
3  MYAPP                               0x0006c0f7 MYAPP + 188663
4  MYAPP                               0x000652a3 MYAPP + 160419
5  Foundation                          0x3512ac29 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 16
6  Foundation                          0x350826d9 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 28
7  Foundation                          0x350826a3 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 198
8  Foundation                          0x350825c5 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
9  CFNetwork                           0x34de77f5 _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 192
10  CFNetwork                          0x34ddc4a5 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 424
11  CFNetwork                          0x34ddc1a3 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 106
12  CFNetwork                          0x34ddc0d9 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 156
13  CoreFoundation                     0x355b9ad3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14  CoreFoundation                     0x355b929f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 214
15  CoreFoundation                     0x355b8045 __CFRunLoopRun + 652
16  CoreFoundation                     0x3553b4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
17  CoreFoundation                     0x3553b36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18  GraphicsServices                   0x371d7439 GSEventRunModal + 136
19  UIKit                              0x33047cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
20  MYAPP                              0x0003fbcf MYAPP + 7119
21  MYAPP                              0x0003fb84 MYAPP + 7044
)
```

From the CoreFoundation etc method names and asking the user what happened, I can get a pretty good idea of where the crash happened.

However, since iOS 6 was released, my crash reports all look like this:

```
CRASH: NSRangeException (*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483670 beyond bounds [0 .. 11])

TRACE: (
0  CoreFoundation                     0x3a3872bb <redacted> + 186
1  libobjc.A.dylib                    0x32ca697f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  CoreFoundation                     0x3a2d1e8d <redacted> + 164
3  MYAPP                              0x000ff721 MYAPP + 214817
4  MYAPP                              0x000e8999 MYAPP + 121241
5  UIKit                              0x372f60ad <redacted> + 72
6  UIKit                              0x372f605f <redacted> + 30
7  UIKit                              0x372f603d <redacted> + 44
8  UIKit                              0x372f58f3 <redacted> + 502
9  UIKit                              0x372e1287 <redacted> + 526
10  UIKit                             0x37373f3d <redacted> + 748
11  UIKit                             0x3721e52b <redacted> + 318
12  UIKit                             0x3720b809 <redacted> + 380
13  UIKit                             0x3720b123 <redacted> + 6154
14  GraphicsServices                  0x362085a3 <redacted> + 590
15  GraphicsServices                  0x362081d3 <redacted> + 34
16  CoreFoundation                    0x3a35c173 <redacted> + 34
17  CoreFoundation                    0x3a35c117 <redacted> + 138
18  CoreFoundation                    0x3a35af99 <redacted> + 1384
19  CoreFoundation                    0x3a2cdebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
20  CoreFoundation                    0x3a2cdd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
21  GraphicsServices                  0x362072eb GSEventRunModal + 74
22  UIKit                             0x3725f301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
23  MYAPP                             0x000ccbd3 MYAPP + 7123
24  MYAPP                             0x000ccb88 MYAPP + 7048
)
```

I get the stack trace from here, which the user is prompted to email when the app is re-opened:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/crashlog.txt", documentsDirectory];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CRASH: %@ (%@)\n\nTRACE: %@", [exception name], [exception reason], [exception callStackSymbols]];
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
}
```

Without the method names, this is worse than useless. Is there any way of getting these method names back into my stack traces? This is a release configuration, not debug.

**EDIT:**

I have followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/970789).

I am extracting the `.app` and `.dSYM` files from the `.xcarchive` package and running `atos -arch armv7 -o 'MyApp.app'/'MyApp'`

However, I am still not getting method names from `atos`.

Comment: Followup - I never did get this to work, so I've abandoned emailing of crash reports and I am now using QuincyKit - a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any iOS 6 betas installed, by chance? I ran into this same problem.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809174/how-to-stop-symbolicate-adding-redacted-pieces-to-ios-crash-log) helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a slightly different problem. The crash log is symbolicated on the user's device, not on my development Mac. Can I symbolicate crash logs on my Mac that came from a user's device, not iTunes connect?

Comment: You can symbolicate as long as you have the dSym of the build from your user's device. The process has likely changed since Xcode became a proper app, but there are likely tutorials on how to do it via Google.

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentions the wrong file to use in his EDIT.

This post has all the info required to get this working:

[Using atos to determine crashed method name with dSYM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654376/using-atos-to-determine-crashed-method-name-with-dsym)

Clear instructions on where to find the correct file to run with atos:

[Atos cannot get symbols from dSYM of archived application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675863/atos-cannot-get-symbols-from-dsym-of-archived-application)

Make sure to use the correct architecture; I was trying to use armv7, but I needed to specify arm64