# Symbolicate iPhone KSCrash JSON Reports

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I have received a few crash reports from users of my app; however, they are in KSCrash's JSON format.  I can tell what the problem is but I can find exactly where the problem is!  Everything I can find to symbolicate the crash report seems to deal with Apple style report and not a lot on KSCrash's JSON format.

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) doesn't seem to support the JSON format.

I have also tried atos (i.e., from [Using atos to determine crashed method name with dSYM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654376/using-atos-to-determine-crashed-method-name-with-dsym) but not sure if I am correctly calculating the addresses correctly.

Please help!

JSON Crash Report:

```
{
"binary_images": [
    {
        "cpu_subtype": 0,
        "cpu_type": 16777228,
        "image_addr": 4295196672,
        "image_size": 524288,
        "image_vmaddr": 4294967296,
        "name": "/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5CEB5AA5-797A-4656-8E41-E3898243DD2C/MYAPP.app/MYAPP",
        "uuid": "C34AC6E9-4A70-3909-89E3-B7621BAC1855"
    },
    ...
    {
        "cpu_subtype": 0,
        "cpu_type": 16777228,
        "image_addr": 6627819520,
        "image_size": 151552,
        "image_vmaddr": 6625312768,
        "name": "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal",
        "uuid": "69F0DA76-836A-3F05-BCF8-A561EC6C467A"
    }
],
"crash": {
    "diagnosis": "Application threw exception NSInvalidArgumentException: (null)\nOriginated at or in a subcall of _mh_execute_header",
    "error": {
        "address": 0,
        "mach": {
            "code": 0,
            "exception": 10,
            "exception_name": "EXC_CRASH",
            "subcode": 0
        },
        "nsexception": {
            "name": "NSInvalidArgumentException",
            "referenced_object": {
                "address": 5896109504,
                "type": "unknown"
            }
        },
        "reason": "-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f6f7dc0",
        "signal": {
            "code": 0,
            "name": "SIGABRT",
            "signal": 6
        },
        "type": "nsexception"
    },
    "threads": [
        {
            "backtrace": {
                "contents": [
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480478100,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480477976,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6826131244,
                        "object_addr": 6826098688,
                        "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                        "symbol_addr": 6826131188,
                        "symbol_name": "objc_exception_throw"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480506028,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480505816,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480493644,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480492772,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6479458908,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6479458816,
                        "symbol_name": "_CF_forwarding_prep_0"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295494968,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295426364,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295392188,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295384932,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295385280,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6570714364,
                        "object_addr": 6570655744,
                        "object_name": "UIKit",
                        "symbol_addr": 6570713740,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562573572,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562573424,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562552096,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562551804,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562551776,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562551744,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562549376,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562549124,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562548692,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562548176,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6562521932,
                        "object_addr": 6562512896,
                        "object_name": "QuartzCore",
                        "symbol_addr": 6562521852,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480179012,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480178980,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480170172,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480169800,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6480171244,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6480170316,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6479304704,
                        "object_addr": 6479265792,
                        "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                        "symbol_addr": 6479304320,
                        "symbol_name": "CFRunLoopRunSpecific"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6664434032,
                        "object_addr": 6664388608,
                        "object_name": "GraphicsServices",
                        "symbol_addr": 6664433852,
                        "symbol_name": "GSEventRunModal"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6571156968,
                        "object_addr": 6570655744,
                        "object_name": "UIKit",
                        "symbol_addr": 6571156764,
                        "symbol_name": "UIApplicationMain"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 4295322808,
                        "object_addr": 4295196672,
                        "object_name": "MYAPP",
                        "symbol_addr": 4295196672,
                        "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6834759864,
                        "object_addr": 6834749440,
                        "object_name": "libdyld.dylib",
                        "symbol_addr": 6834759860,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    }
                ],
                "skipped": 0
            },
            "crashed": true,
            "current_thread": true,
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "backtrace": {
                "contents": [
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6835930524,
                        "object_addr": 6835814400,
                        "object_name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib",
                        "symbol_addr": 6835930516,
                        "symbol_name": "kevent_qos"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6834634084,
                        "object_addr": 6834552832,
                        "object_name": "libdispatch.dylib",
                        "symbol_addr": 6834633852,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    },
                    {
                        "instruction_addr": 6834566092,
                        "object_addr": 6834552832,
                        "object_name": "libdispatch.dylib",
                        "symbol_addr": 6834566040,
                        "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                    }
                ],
                "skipped": 0
            },
            "crashed": false,
            "current_thread": false,
            "index": 1,
            "registers": {
                "basic": {
                    "cpsr": 0,
                    "fp": 6140552752,
                    "lr": 6834634084,
                    "pc": 6835930524,
                    "sp": 6140552608,
                    "x0": 3,
                    "x1": 6944956928,
                    "x10": 0,
                    "x11": 0,
                    "x12": 24,
                    "x13": 33554431,
                    "x14": 0,
                    "x15": 5895038864,
                    "x16": 374,
                    "x17": 0,
                    "x18": 0,
                    "x19": 6944821248,
                    "x2": 1,
                    "x20": 6944821248,
                    "x21": 6944821248,
                    "x22": 6944956800,
                    "x23": 6944960512,
                    "x24": 6944960512,
                    "x25": 0,
                    "x26": 6140555520,
                    "x27": 6140555520,
                    "x28": 0,
                    "x29": 6140552752,
                    "x3": 6140552616,
                    "x4": 1,
                    "x5": 0,
                    "x6": 0,
                    "x7": 0,
                    "x8": 6944956864,
                    "x9": 0
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
},
"process": {},
"report": {
    "id": "93239236-359A-44AC-8AAA-9AB2ACCE30DA",
    "process_name": "MYAPP",
    "timestamp": "2015-07-17T23:35:51Z",
    "type": "standard",
    "version": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 0
    }
},
"system": {
    "CFBundleExecutable": "MYAPP",
    "CFBundleExecutablePath": "/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5CEB5AA5-797A-4656-8E41-E3898243DD2C/MYAPP.app/MYAPP",
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "ca.mymojo.CJ-Stats",
    "CFBundleName": "MYAPP",
    "CFBundleShortVersionString": "1.1.2",
    "CFBundleVersion": "1.1.2",
    "app_start_time": "2015-07-17T23:35:47Z",
    "app_uuid": "C34AC6E9-4A70-3909-89E3-B7621BAC1855",
    "application_stats": {
        "active_time_since_last_crash": 3.93054,
        "active_time_since_launch": 3.93054,
        "application_active": true,
        "application_in_foreground": true,
        "background_time_since_last_crash": 0,
        "background_time_since_launch": 0,
        "launches_since_last_crash": 1,
        "sessions_since_last_crash": 1,
        "sessions_since_launch": 1
    },
    "binary_cpu_subtype": 0,
    "binary_cpu_type": 16777228,
    "boot_time": "2015-07-17T12:07:09Z",
    "cpu_arch": "arm64",
    "cpu_subtype": 1,
    "cpu_type": 16777228,
    "device_app_hash": "58ebd0a220c47528a58b7d2426b69ce4b5491e14",
    "jailbroken": false,
    "kernel_version": "Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Mon Jun 29 00:33:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.1.36.0.1~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T7000",
    "machine": "iPhone7,2",
    "memory": {
        "free": 27996160,
        "size": 1035993088,
        "usable": 825868288
    },
    "model": "N61AP",
    "os_version": "13A4293g",
    "parent_process_id": 1,
    "parent_process_name": "unknown",
    "process_id": 4791,
    "process_name": "MYAPP",
    "system_name": "iPhone OS",
    "system_version": "9.0",
    "time_zone": "CDT"
},
"user": {}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

I needed to use KSCrashReportFilterAppleFmt to convert the file to .crash file which then I could load into Xcode which happily symbolised it for me.  The code I used to convert is below, if anyone else finds this useful.

```
NSString *srcFilePath = @"crash-report.json";
NSString *destFilePath = @"crash-report.crash";

NSData *myJSON = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:srcFilePath];

NSError* localError = nil;

NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myJSON options:0 error:&localError];

if(localError != nil)
{
    return ;
}

id filter = [KSCrashReportFilterAppleFmt filterWithReportStyle:KSAppleReportStyleSymbolicatedSideBySide];

NSArray *reports = @[parsedJSON];
[filter filterReports:reports
         onCompletion:^(NSArray *filteredReports, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
             if(error != nil) {
                 return;
             }

             if(completed) {
                 NSString *contents = [filteredReports objectAtIndex:0];
                 [contents  writeToFile:destFilePath
                           atomically:YES
                               encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                                error:nil];
             }
         }];
```